# jQuery dataTables : colVis not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm not able to get colvis working using the code:

```
var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis( table );
```

If I initialize colVis using the "C" option in the Dom, it works.

see live example of problem here: http://live.datatables.net/idinat/115/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have the code from this example -> **http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/examples/new_init.html**

In your code, you lack the `.info` `<div>` -> `<div class="info">...</div>`

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis( table );
$( colvis.button() ).insertAfter('div.info');
```

When you initialize dataTables with `C` in the `dom` option string, then dataTables automatically will initialize `ColVis` and insert the `ColVis` button. If not, you must create `ColVis` programmatically *and* insert the button programmatically.

So the answer is, in your case, that it *is* working though the button is not visible because it is placed after an element that not exists. Instead of inserting after `.info` you could insert before your own `.container` or `<table>` :

```js
$( colvis.button() ).insertAfter('div.container');
$( colvis.button() ).insertBefore('#example');
```

etc, or insert the button into the datatables control itself :

```js
$( colvis.button() ).prependTo('#example_wrapper');
```

dataTables always create a wrapper with the id `<table_id>_wrapper`.

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vr5QL/**

Comment: Thank you David, I have it working now. Could you tell me how to change the options when initializing this way? eg.     colvis.s.aiExclude[0]

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks again for your help, David.

Comment: David, Can you tell me, If I have 20 columns how can I move around the 20 columns in the show/hide button?(Where do I keep these 20 columns)

Comment: @Prabhakar, unfortunately you cannot arrange the order of the column-titles in the dropdown, but you can [**rebuild**](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/api#rebuild) the order if the columns have been moved around programmatically, as with the [**ColReorder-plugin**](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/)

Comment: I receive this error in Laravel 9.0 App "$.fn.dataTable.ColVis is not a constructor"